# Numbers app: how to change x axis position + change chart's line width

Tags: iwork, numbers

I have a regular linear graph and have y values running from negative to positive, enabling x axis shows the line at the bottom of the graph. How is it possible to set it to show at zero, i.e. running from the origin (0,0)?

I also wonder how to change the width of the line? I can change the size of the "data symbol", but can't find for the line itself.

**UPD:** This is easily possible to do in Excel, so it will be surprising if Numbers can't do it.

Comment: It's been a while, already. Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question, please see this [Answer to Force line chart to show axis at point (0, 0)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/190041/120171)

**Second part:**
Select the line to highlight it.  Then under **Style** in the Inspector the Connection Line and weight can be adjusted by point.

[image: Ligne weight]