# Numbers for Mac: Force line chart to show axis at point (0, 0)

Tags: mac, numbers

Look at [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rh88i1zb8n1sz6m/Snap%202014-11-14%20at%2009.21.22%2C%20626x481.png?dl=0) line chart.

I wonder if its possible to force Numbers to show `Y=0`, for example, without needing to add a data entry point to make it happen.

*- Is it possible?*

Answer (score 1):

In the inspector, one can set the Axis Scale to a minimum value.

[image: Inspector Axis settings]

The resulting chart starts at 0 when minimum is set.

[image: Line Chart Y=0]